# Terraform elasticbeanstalk deploy

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

Does Terraform support application deployment using ElasticBeanstalk?

I've tried to deploy Spring Boot app using

```
`aws_elastic_beanstalk_application`, 
`aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version` 
`aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment`
```

directives, but noticed it creates Elastic Beanstalk application, application version and environment, but does not deploy actual .jar file. I have to use `aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment` command to make it work.

Comment: You could a null resource to deploy the app or do the update. https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html

Answer (score 3):

The current version of Terraform just creates the s3 bucket, uploads your source code and then creates the application version in the elastic beanstalk.

To Deploy the version, use AWS CLI:

```sh
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment \
    --application-name test-app \
    --version-label latest \
    --environment-name test-env
```